# SQL left join avoid null entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, left-join

I have a table: phone which I want to left join it to base table customer (customer_id as PK). I am getting duplicate rows after joining this. I need to arrange number column into 3 separate columns as Phone Number, Fax Number and Cell Number based on the query on description column.

Phone:

[image]

This is what I tried

```
select cust.customer_id, customer_phone_id,
CASE
    WHEN description like '%OFFICE%' or description like '%PHONE%' THEN number
    ELSE null
END AS [Phone Number],
CASE
    WHEN description like '%FAX%' THEN number
    ELSE null
END AS [Fax Number],
CASE
    WHEN description like '%CELL%' or description like '%MOBILE%' THEN number
    ELSE null
END AS [Cell Number] 
from customer cust 
left join customer_phone ph on cust.customer_id=ph.customer_id and ph.number is not null
order by customer_phone_id desc
```

But getting these in multiple rows which I want to avoid

[image]

I want to have only one row finally with all these values in it.
This is what I want as a result:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which customer_phone_id do you want?

Comment: You can use MAX on every CASE, group by customer_id. But you need to remove customer_phone_id (or usa MAX even there).

Comment: @Aww_Geez: Sorry I forgot to mention that, I want to have the MAX id on that (customer_phone_id) as a latest entry. If phone number is null I can go for the second recent. Infact not really given much importance to that as long as we got all the 3 entries

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation:

```sql
select 
    c.customer_id, 
    max(cp.customer_phone_id) customer_phone_id,
    max(case when cp.description like '%OFFICE%' or cp.description like '%PHONE%' then cp.number end) as phone_number,
    max(case when cp.description like '%FAX%' then cp.number end) as fax_number,
    max(case when cp.description like '%CELL%' or cp.description like '%MOBILE%' then cp.number end) as cell_number
from customer c
left join customer_phone cp on c.customer_id = cp.customer_id 
group by c.customer_id
order by customer_phone_id desc
```

Comment: you need to aggregate also customer_phone_id (or delete it) as it is unique... but from last comment think you need to MAX also that

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty quick and dirty, but might be what you're looking for. . . It'll "collapse" everything into a single row, assuming 1 each occurrence of the fields you're looking for.

for customer_phone_id i'm chopping off the number at the end of the customer_phone_id field, because we know the length of the customer_id + 1 for the underscore.

```
select 
    cust.customer_id, 
    CONCAT(cust.customer_id, '_', MAX(RIGHT(customer_phone_id,  LEN(customer_phone_id)-1-LEN(customer_id)))) customer_phone_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN description like '%OFFICE%' or description like '%PHONE%' THEN number
        ELSE null END) AS [Phone Number],
    MAX(CASE WHEN description like '%FAX%' THEN number
        ELSE null END) AS [Fax Number],
    MAX(CASE WHEN description like '%CELL%' or description like '%MOBILE%' THEN number
        ELSE null END) AS [Cell Number] 
from 
    customer cust 
    left join customer_phone ph on cust.customer_id=ph.customer_id and ph.number is not null
group by
    cust.customer_id
order by 
    customer_phone_id desc
```

Comment: why simply do not MAX(customer_phone_id)?

Comment: Because to be absolutely honest, I don't know how MAX when using a string works.

Comment: Strings made of numbers are ordered from 0 to 9 on every digits, since the root is the same the only variable is the last number... and MAX will return the bigger one IF they remain between 0-9. For exemple if will exit _10 it will be minor of _2

Comment: so a max alone would work, so long as the digits following '_' stay under 10?

Comment: Yes, but for the whole query to work customer_phone_id (with phone no null) must be at max 3, a 4 number will result in the MAX(CASE ....) to hide an existing phone number (it will take the max, following the same rules)

Comment: True, we don't know if the OPs database may have more than one of each phone number returned. If it does, data will be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
   cust.customer_id,
   ph_cell.customer,
   ''phone_number,
   ph_fax.number Fax_number,
   ph_cell.number Cell_number 
from
   customer cust 
   left join
      phone ph_cell 
      on cust.customer_id = ph_cell.customer 
      and ph_cell.descriptions = 'cell' 
   left join
      phone ph_fax 
      on cust.customer_id = ph_fax.customer 
      and ph_fax.descriptions = 'fax'
```